# I need to override the search term

Tags: magento2, backend, catalogsearch

I need override **\vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\Model\Layer\Search\Plugin\CollectionFilter.php** File,
i need get the search term and replace "-" and "." for nothing. Which a best method for make this?
I know how to override view files in my design theme but i don't know how to override Model files.

Example:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Search\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory;

/**
 * Catalog search plugin for search collection filter in layered navigation.
 */
class CollectionFilter
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory
     */
    protected $queryFactory;

    /**
     * @param QueryFactory $queryFactory
     */
    public function __construct(QueryFactory $queryFactory)
    {
        $this->queryFactory = $queryFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Add search filter criteria to search collection
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search\CollectionFilter $subject
     * @param null $result
     * @param \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $collection
     * @param Category $category
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterFilter(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search\CollectionFilter $subject,
        $result,
        $collection,
        Category $category
    ) {
        /** @var \Magento\Search\Model\Query $query */
        $query = $this->queryFactory->get();
        if (!$query->isQueryTextShort()) {
            $text = $query->getQueryText();
            $text = str_replace(array("-","."),"",$text);
            $collection->addSearchFilter($text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to edit this before it gets to the model and the collection. My suggestion is to create an observer on the `controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index` event:

in your module, in `etc/frontend/events.xml` file, add:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_catalogsearch_result_index">
        <observer name="change_query_text" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeQueryText"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

in your observer class `Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeQueryText.php`, you can do the following:

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

/**
 * Class ChangeQueryText
 * @package Vendor\Module\Observer
 */
class ChangeQueryText implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $request;

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $queryString = trim($this->request->getQuery('q'));
        $newQuery = preg_replace('/[\-\.]/', '', $queryString);
        $this->request->setParam('q', $newQuery);
    }
}
```

Code is not tested but should work properly in theory :)

Comment: Worked for me, you are the best!

Comment: Glad I could help! Cheers!